# How to declare Multiple hasOne relation in laravel 5.2

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5, has-one

Hi I have 7 tables in  my database ,

All 6 tables are has user_id from user table,

In user model I am declaring hasOne relation as below

```
 public function profiledetailsHasOne()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profiledetails');
}


public function educationHasOne()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Education');
}
public function occupationHasOne()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Occupation');
}

public function maritalHasOne()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Marital');
}
public function parentHasOne(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Parent');
 }
```

I am wondering there must other way rather than using this cluster way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to comment on the structure but the way you do is right.

I would just remove HasOne word from functions so they read nicer when accessing the relations like below.

```
$user->profileDetails();
$user->education();
```

instead of

```
$user->profiledetailsHasOne();
$user->educationHasOne();
```